# How to select a child class based on an attribute in Python

Tags: python, django

For a Django project I have a parent class and several child classes.
In the Django admin backend I want to have the ability to select the right child class and use its properties and methods.

This is what I had in mind:

```
class Parent:
    _name = "parent"

class Child1(Parent):
    _name = "child 1"

class Child2(Parent):
    _name = "child 2"
```

In the admin the user should be able to select "child 1" or "child 2" from a dropdown.

Later on in an API the child class should be selected based on the property name.

Ofcourse I could just create a dictionary containing the class names and the property names, and later on use a lot of `if` and `elif` statements, but that would not be the proper thing to do.

How could I solve this, or am I just thinking in the entirely wrong direction?

Answer (score 1):

Make a dictionary containing the Child classes with the property as key and then always use it like:

```
class Parent:
    _name = "parent"

class Child1(Parent):
    _name = "child 1"

class Child2(Parent):
    _name = "child 2"

mydict = {'thisone': Child1, 'thatone': Child2}

myinstance = mydict['thisone']()
```

you can even do:

```
mydict = {Child1._name: Child1, 
          Child2._name: Child2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use str:

```
class Parent(object):
    _name = "parent"
    def __str__(self):
        return self._name
```

Try:

```
>>> class Parent(object):
>>>    _name = "parent"
>>>    def __str__(self):
>>>        return self._name

>>> class Child1(Parent):
>>>    _name = "child 1"    
>>> class Child2(Parent):
>>>    _name = "child 2"

>>> c1 = Child1()
>>> c2 = Child2()
>>> print c1
child 1
>>> print c2
child 2
```

Comment: __str__ should return a value, not print it